# Converting trace to $2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Assuming $x$ and $y$ are two vectors, I have an optimiztion problem with the following objective function

$$f(x,y)=\mbox{tr}((y-x)x^{\top})$$

Is it possible to convert the above to a norm-$2$, like $f(x,y)=\| \cdot \|_2^2$?

Comment: If $u,v$ are vectors then $\mathrm{trace}\left(uv^{\top}\right) = u\cdot v$, where $\cdot$ is the inner product.

Answer (score 4):

$\text{trace}(X X^\top) = \sum_{i,j} X_{ij}^2 = \|X\|_2^2$.

$$f(x,y) = \text{trace}((y-x)x^\top) = \left\|\frac{y}{2}\right\|_2^2  - \left\|x-\frac{y}{2}\right\|_2^2$$

Answer (score 2):

If $u,v$ are vectors then $\mathrm{trace}\left(uv^{\top}\right) = u\cdot v$, where $\cdot$ is the inner product.

So $$\mathrm{trace}\left((y-x)x^{\top}\right)=(y-x)\cdot x=y\cdot x - \|x\|^2$$

Comment: you are right, but i want to know if i can put it all in a single $\| \|^2$ ?

Comment: No, because it is often negative. @Bob

Comment: You do get a formula $f(x,y)+f(y,x)=-\|x-y\|^2$. @Bob